# Параллельное обновление таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, есть процедура, которая содержит в себе запрос вида:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) table
SET SessionId=@SessionId
Where SessionId is null
```

Если эту процедуру будут запускать параллельно несколько пользователей, то не будет ли коллизий в том, что одном и тот же юзер проапдейтит одну и туже запись или MS SQL сервер позаботится, что бы такой ситуации не возникло?

Если такое имеет место быть, то как этого избежать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37799974/4269118

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Такая конструкция потокобезопасна.

> или MS SQL сервер позаботится, чтобы такой ситуации не возникло?

Если кратко, то - да. Если одна сессия (имеется ввиду SQL-сессия) выбрала запись в таблице для обновления, то параллельная сессия не сможет (из-за установленной первой сессией U-блокировки) выбрать и обновить ту же самую запись (если я правильно понял - это то, что интересует). Пример с пояснениями - ниже.

---

Пусть есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE LockTest
(
    Id int identity not NULL primary key,
    SessionId uniqueidentifier NULL
);
```

Добавим в неё немного данных:

```
INSERT INTO LockTest (SessionId)
VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL);
```

Пару раз выполним запрос:

```
DECLARE
    @sessionId uniqueidentifier = newid();

UPDATE TOP (1) LockTest
SET SessionId = @sessionId
WHERE SessionId IS NULL;
```

Выполним запрос на обновление в третий раз, запустив, предварительно профилировщик, и посмотрим какие происходят блокировки:

[image: update top (1) locks]

(для полноты понимания происходящего желательно, конечно, иметь представление о [режимах](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175519.aspx), [гранулярности](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189849.aspx) и [совместимости](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186396.aspx) блокировок).

Происходит примерно следующее. SqlServer сканирует кластерный индекс в поисках записи, у которой `SessionId` является `NULL`. При этом для каждой записи поочередно:

- ставится U-блокировка на запись (чтение с возможным изменением данных)
- происходит проверка условия `SessionId IS NULL`
- если запись не удовлетворяет условию, то блокировка снимается и
  происходит переход к следующей записи (на снимке экрана - это
  *Acquired*-*Released* пары U-блокировок записей со значениями хэшей
  ключа `(8194443284a0)` и `(61a06abd401c)`)
- если запись удовлетворяет условию (запись со значением хэша ключа
  `(98ec012aa510)`), то блокировка повышается до монопольной
  (X-блокировки), запись обновляется, после чего блокировки снимаются

Параллельная сессия не сможет обновить ту же самую запись, т.к. для этого ей придётся точно также установить U-блокировку на ту же самую запись. Однако две U-блокировки несовместимы, поэтому параллельной сессии придётся ждать, пока мы обновим запись и/или снимем блокировку. Тогда же, когда блокировка нами будет уже снята, `SessionId` у записи станет не `NULL`. Вследствие чего параллельной сессии придётся искать следующую "свободную" запись.

Картина происходящего может несколько меняться в зависимости от наличия или отсутствия индекса на столбце `SessionId`. От того, будет ли проиcходить *lock-escalation* (для `TOP (1)`, наверное, не должно). Однако характер происходящего, - установка U-блокировки на кандидата и её освобождение, если запись не подошла, либо преобразование в X-блокировку, если запись выбрана, с последующим освобождением, - скорее всего будет сохраняться.